# Is there a way to apply metaballs on large scale?

Tags: metaballs

I want to make a high quality rendering of molecular dynamics simulations (10k-100k elements) and melt bound particles together into some form of coherent mass.

Metaballs should be the way to go, as they allow me to choose differently sized spheres for particles and control the level of cohesion nicely.
However, they don't appear to make any use of multi-threading or GPU at all. If I crank up the render resolution setting, one core gets occupied and seemingly nothing happens for a reaaally long time. How do people apply them for rendering fluids..?

Am I missing something? Any solutions or ideas for workarounds are appreciated!

Comment: +1 relevant to my current interests, metaballs kind of suck

Comment: maybe molecular add-on can help you?